# Visual Studio Code Cordova Extension

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-code, taco

Good morning!

I updated Visual Studio Code yesterday and now my Cordova extension is failing. I am getting this error:

[cordova-debug-adapter] TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like add the "cwd" attribute to each debug scenario in the .vscode/launch.json file fixed the problem. There is a pull request to get it permanently added to further releases.

`{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run Android on device",
            "cwd": "${cwd}",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "target": "device",
            "port": 9222,
            "sourceMaps": true
        },`

Additional information https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova/issues/48

Answer (score 1):

A new version of the extension was pushed to the marketplace which addresses this issue. After updating the extension existing projects will need to either include the "cwd": attribute as described above or delete the generated launch.json (if you haven't modified it) so that it can be regenerated correctly.